# Why didn't virtual ubuntu halts clearly?

Tags: virtualbox

I am running Ubuntu 11.10 on Oracle Virtual Box 4.2.4 under Windows 7 x64.

To stop guest system I often use `halt` command which works fine on physical machines. But it looks hanging on virtual ubunty. After `halt` it starts shutting down, Ubuntu logo appears with dots below flashing. After some cycles it just stops. VM manager does not feel machine is gone, so I need to power off it.

**P.S.**

The system stops Ok if I shutdown it via GUI.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be using `halt`, especially in a VM. These are the Three Shutdown commands and their meanings:

- `halt` brings the system down to its lowest state, but leaves it powered on.
- `shutdown` brings the system down to its lowest state, and will turn off power (soft power switch) if it can. Most computers now can do so.
- `reboot` restarts the system. It brings the system down to its lowest state, then starts it up again.

As you can see `halt` only exits the OS, it doesn't Power off the machine. You should use a different command. I recommend you use the `sudo shutdown -P now` command in Terminal. Or if you want to use the VirtualBox Quit Menu then "Send the ShutDown Signal" should work if you have the Power Settings setup right in the VM.

That should work fine for you. Why you were using `halt`, I don't understand.

Comment: I was using `halt` historically: it was working on physical machines.

Comment: Well, lessons are learned and we move on. Tis Be Life :)